# Win10 Printer Properties is missing USB Ports with Dymo Printer

Tags: windows-10, usb, printer

I am using a Dymo LabelWriter 450 connected to a USB port, but in the Printer Properties, under the Ports tab, *no* USB ports show up in the list:

[image: Port list is missing all USB ports]

When researching this online, most results point to a Windows bug about these ports being missing after disconnecting the device, summarized by Microsoft as:

> **Symptoms**
>
> If you connect a USB printer to Windows 10 version 1903 or
> later, then shut down Windows and disconnect or shut off the printer,
> when you start Windows again the USB printer port will not be
> available in the list of printer ports. Windows will not be able to
> complete any task that requires that port.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/usb-printer-port-missing-after-disconnecting-printer-while-windows-10-version-1903-or-later-is-shut-down-e1c36061-0dd9-26f4-0104-4c7b6538cf81

However, the suggested course of action to restart the computer with the USB printer connected does nothing to help the situation.

How do you get all the USB ports to show up in the list in Printer Properties?

Answer (score 1):

Even though their suggested course of action did not solve the problem, Microsoft's description of the cause is still the actual reason that the USB ports don't show up. The cause, as described by Microsoft:

> **Cause**
>
> If the driver for the USB printer contains a Language Monitor, the
> OpenPortEx callback function of the Language Monitor would not be
> called.  As a result, the user cannot fulfill operations dependent on
> the operation of the Language Monitor.

It turns out that the Dymo driver (version `8.3.0.443` in my case) uses a "Language Monitor". I found [this conversation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2a5bf810-bc60-47e2-aee5-f5464a018434/w2016-redirected-printers-not-working-win32-error-code-returned-by-the-print-processor-50-the?forum=winserverTS) that mentions "the DYMO printer driver uses a Language Monitor" and shows how to disable it:

- As an Administrator start regedit
- Navigate to the following key
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3]
- Select the DYMO printer
- On the right select Monitor and either double click it, or right click and choose Modify
- Delete the value leaving it blank and click OK
- Restart the Print Spooler service

(I did not do that last step of restarting the Print Spooler service.)

After I disabled the Language Monitor in the registry, the USB port shows up correctly in the Printer Properties:

[image]

After doing the above, you might have to unplug your Dymo Printer from the USB port, and then plug it back in to trigger the printer to be added as a USB printer.